# Add a boolean field vs check if field IS NOT NULL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

We use tables that require admin approval of records before the records become publicly visible. I am wondering what the most appropriate way would be to design such a table where the main query is to retrieve records that have been approved (or not yet approved).

Assuming the queried column will be indexed:

1. Is there any speed benefit to using a boolean field?
2. Is checking whether a column is NULL go against best practices?

For example:

```
id | title | text | approved_dttm
---------------------------------------
1  | ...   | ...  | null 
2  | ...   | ...  | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 ETC


SELECT * FROM table where approved_dttm IS NOT NULL;
```

vs

```
id | title | text | approved | approved_dttm
---------------------------------------
1  | ...   | ...  | 0        | null 
2  | ...   | ...  | 1        | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 ETC


SELECT * FROM table where approved = 1;
```

Note: We do not need multiple states other than approved/not-approved. No "needs further review" etc.

Comment: IMHO stick with an approved date, the boolean adds redundant data (if approved date is set, it must be approved).  NULL is so widely used it is a common thing for people to work with.

Comment: What would you do with approved that you cannot do with approved_dttm?  If the answer is nothing, I would drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: Is there any speed benefit to using a boolean field?**

A: NO.

In this case, it's very unlikely that there would be any query would obtain a "speed benefit" from using the `approved` column vs `approved_dttm IS [NOT] NULL`.

While the additional byte for the approved column is negligible (assuming that's defined as TINYINT, that extra byte will not really impact the number of rows that "fit" in a block)... an *index* on that column would not be negligible. That would require additional blocks (space), and would add overhead for maintenance of the index entries.

We can't exclude some exceptional corner case where the addition of that column would be of benefit, but in general, given the information provided, no, there's no "speed benefit" to adding that column.

(And we're setting aside here a discussion of redundant data and update anomalies... adding the (redundant) `approved` column flies in the face of third normal form, and the familiar mantra "Every attribute is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key. So help me Codd".)

**Q: Is checking whether a column is NULL go against best practices?**

A: NO.

It doesn't go against any "best practices" I'm aware of. The `NULL` and tri-valued boolean logic has been around forever (since E.F.Codd first coined "relational" in 1970, the advent of System/R and Oracle in 1977, and DB2 in 1983, ...)

Some set of application developers may not like (or understand) how to deal with the nuances of NULL values. And it's true that having a column defined as NOT NULL may somewhat ease their burden. But in my book, "avoiding dealing with NULLs" is *not* a "best practice".

We do note that there are some quirks with some database implementations, not making use of an index to satisfy a `col IS NULL` predicate. But those quirks are usually overcome with appropriately defined indexes and carefully written queries. Understanding NULL values and their quirks and dealing with it *is* a "best practice".

Answer (score 0):

1) Adding the `approved` field just duplicates the information that can be derived from `approved_dttm`, so there is no point adding it from an information point of view.

2) From an indexing point of view you could argue that an index on a Boolean (well, tinyint) field is smaller than indexing a datetime field. However, the selectivity of this index would be low (there are only 2 possible values), therefore there is a fair chance that MySQL would ignore such index when actually selecting the data.

All in all, I would not add an extra Boolean field to indicate if an entry was approved.